# Reducing an array size by averaging

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, compression, ienumerable

I have a large sampled waveform and I would like to log a compressed version of it for diagnostics by re-sampling it (with averaging) to a lower rate.  The lower rate will always be an even divisor of the original rate.
Ex: Compress a 32K waveform to a 4K waveform by averaging 8 sample chunks.

Is there a easy way to do this using Linq/IEnumerable

Comment: @Aybe What do you mean?

Comment: Maybe that your approach might not preserve characteristics of the signal that you would find valuable, peak-to-peak amplitude for one. Consider asking at [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) (though I can't say what's on-topic there).

Comment: What I am requesting will achieve my intent.  The situation is that I am logging the results of a waveform digitizer (similar to an oscilloscope) and I need to capture another signal that requires a faster sampling rate; but, I want the presently logged channels to stay them same.  I have used Linq before to do something similar; but, I don't use it often and I wanted to see how someone else would achieve the results.  CPU time is probably not a factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite pure Linq, but this will do it:

```
int divisor = 2;
int index = 0;
var cutSamples = samples
    .GroupBy(s => index++ / divisor)
    .Select(g => g.Average());
```

Linq is not your friend when it comes to performance, so this will be far faster:

```
public static double[] CutSamples(double[] samples, int divisor)
{
    var reducedSamples = new double[samples.Length / divisor];
    int reducedIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < samples.Length; i += divisor)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < divisor && (i + j) < samples.Length; j++)
        {
            sum += samples[i + j];
            count++;
        }

        reducedSamples[reducedIndex++] = sum / count;
    }

    return reducedSamples;
}
```

Comment: Why do you say that loops are faster than Linq?  Has there been a study/report on that?

Comment: Linq is at best equal in performance to hand written code. The majority of the time it's slower - sometimes drastically so, like in this case. The GroupBy is a generic thing which groups elements based on a key. But in order for it to iterate through any group, it has to actually build every single group by iterating over each item and allocating memory. That means it's slower and it uses far more memory.

Comment: I recommend you try both, and see which one you like more. For small array sizes, the Linq version will be perfectly fine.